# facebook send dialog callback not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui

I'm using the facebook send dialog, and want to redirect to a URL when the dialog closes.

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'send',
   link: 'http://***.com', 
   redirect_uri: '****', // publicly available URL
   description: '***',
   picture: '***',
   to: userId
   },
);
```

The message sends and the iframe closes, but does not redirect. Can I uses FB.ui for this, or do I need to build in another callback function?

Answer (score 0):

If sending the message is successful, the user will be redirected to the redirect_uri. Otherwise, an error will be shown.

As per facebook documentation there is no callback for send method

please refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: The redirect does not seem to be working, so I'm wondering if something needs to be adjusted in my code--or if it's a problem with FB.ui, if I should use a separate callback function.

Comment: try giving display as iframe/popup .. reference url:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

Comment: The facebook documentation doesn't provide a complete list of the parameters accepted by the send dialog - it accepts a number of the feed dialog's parameters, which aren't listed on the doc.